# Key Pressed wont work

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, arrow-keys

Im having trouble getting the key pressed event to work, it doesn't recognize key input, can someone please help?

I have three classes player, exe, and board

Here is the board class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
private Timer timer;
private Player player;

//private Floor

public Board() {

    addKeyListener( new TAdapter() );
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    player = new Player();
    //floor = new Floor();

    timer = new Timer(5, this);
    timer.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.drawImage(player.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(), this);
    // g2d.drawImage(floor.getImage(), floor.getX(), floor.getY(), this);
    //System.out.println(player.getX() + ", " + player.getY());
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // checkPlayerOnGround();
    player.move();
    repaint();  
}

private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter implements KeyListener{

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        player.keyReleased(e);
        System.out.println("Released");
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        player.keyPressed(e);
        System.out.println("Pressed");

    }
}
```

}

here is the player class

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class Player{

private String player = "player.jpg";
private int moveX;
private int moveY;
private int x;
private int y;
private Image image;
private boolean canFall = false;

//private Timer jumpTimer = new Timer();
boolean canJump = true;

public Player() {
    ImageIcon playeriImage = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(player));
    image = playeriImage.getImage();
    x = 40;
    y = 60;
}

public void checkFall() {
    if(canFall) {
        moveY = -4;
    }
}

public void move() {
    //checkFall();
    x = moveX + x;
    y  = moveY + y;

}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        moveX = -4;

    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        moveX = 4;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        if(canJump)
            this.jump();

    }

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        moveX = 0;

    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        moveX = 0;

    }

}
```

here is the exe class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Exe extends JFrame {

public Exe() {

    add(new Board());

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("TSA Video Game");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Exe();

}
```

}

thanks in advance

Comment: See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyListener` will only respond to key events IF the component is focusable AND has focus.

It would be better to use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which will allow you to overcome this limitation (if you want to)

I would also recommend that you override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.  You should also not be calling `Graphics#dispose`, as you did not create the `Graphics` context, this could actually prevent anything from being painted on some systems

I would also suggest that a delay of 5 milliseconds (on your Timer) might be a little excessive (5 milliseconds = 200fps!).

A value of 16 (60fps) or 40 (25fps) may be more suitable and reduce the overhead on the system...IMHO

Comment: Yes, but he has `setFocusable(true);`

Comment: @MaximShoustin But they haven't asked for focus, so the panel doesn't have focus. Also, the panel has no means of actually obtaining focus (just because a user clicks on it, won't bring it onto focus by itself)